# TCP connection fails

Tags: c++, tcp, connection, client

I wrote server and client code client can connect with server normally but only on local address i don't know how to connect over internet

```
int main()
{
    struct addrinfo host_info;
    struct addrinfo * host_list;
    struct sockaddr sa;
    struct sockaddr_in ip4addr;

    memset(&host_info, 0, sizeof host_info);

    host_info.ai_family = AF_INET;     // IP version not specified. Can be both.
    host_info.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    getaddrinfo(NULL, "5555", &host_info, &host_list);
    int s;
    s=socket(host_list->ai_family,host_list->ai_socktype,host_list->ai_protocol);
    if(s==-1) printf("error\n");

    int status = connect(s, host_list->ai_addr, host_list->ai_addrlen);
    if (status == -1)  printf("connect error\n");

    char *message="Hi there!";
    send(s, message, 10, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to change NULL in getaddrinfo to ip address but it always fail to connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which TCP/IP address are you trying to connect to, over the internet?

getaddrinfo() should have an IP address of some sort, or it won't know where to connect. It's like trying to send a letter in the mail without an address on it.

Furthermore, there are a LOT of reasons you might not be able to connect. Your firewall could be blocking something... there could be a firewall on the other end that's blocking something... AV software could even be detecting a connection that it thinks is "weird," and blocking it... the IP address could be wrong.

It'd be helpful for you to talk about the troubleshooting that you've done and what you're seeing.